# Inconsistent behavior in static_casting between CUDA and C++

Tags: c++, cuda

I'm trying to figure out why the following behavior is inconsistent between CUDA and C++. Note that the values of x is exactly the same, its the static_casting that seems to be inconsistent.

```c
#include <cstdio>

template<typename RealType>
long long __host__ __device__ __forceinline__ FLOAT_TO_FIXED(RealType v) {
    return (long long)(v);
}

void __global__ debug_gpu(double x) {
    printf("x %.5f -x %.5f gpu %lld %lld\n", x, -x, FLOAT_TO_FIXED(-x), -FLOAT_TO_FIXED(x));
}

void debug_cpu(double x) {
    printf("x %.5f -x %.5f cpu %lld %lld\n", x, -x, FLOAT_TO_FIXED(-x), -FLOAT_TO_FIXED(x));  
}

int main() {
    double x = static_cast<double>(131154376256114819072.0);
    debug_gpu<<<1, 1>>>(x);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    debug_cpu(x);
}

/*
x 131154376256114819072.00000 -x -131154376256114819072.00000 gpu -9223372036854775808 -9223372036854775807
x 131154376256114819072.00000 -x -131154376256114819072.00000 cpu -9223372036854775808 -9223372036854775808
*/
```

Comment: That looks like more significant figures than a `double` is necessarily able to handle.

Comment: That is correct, but both the CPU and the GPU code receive an identical bit pattern.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be negating a 64-bit value of -9223372036854775808, which causes a signed integer overflow (the value of 9223372036854775808 is not representable in a 64-bit signed integer). This is [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) in C and C++. This means you can get whatever result, depending on the compiler and the hardware executing the program.

Comment: Thank you - this seems to be non-culprit. I was unable to find a non-overflowing float that can reproduce the same behavior.

Comment: @proteneer If you mean you couldn't find a FP value that would cause overflow on negation then that's not surprising. IEEE 754 floating point types have a dedicated sign bit, so the ranges of positive and negative values are the same (sans the sign).